# Erasure - Generic Type information after compilation

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I came across the below in a book-

```
//Here, T is bound by Object by default.
class Gen<T> {
    T ob; // here, T will be replaced by Object

    Gen(T o) {
        ob = o;
    }

//Return ob.
    T getob() {
        return ob;
    }
}
```

---

```
// Here, T is bound by String.
class GenStr<T extends String> {
    T str; // here, T will be replaced by String
    GenStr(T o) {
      str = o;
    }
    T getstr() { return str; }
}
```

After these two classes are compiled, the `T` in `Gen` will be replaced by `Object`. The `T` in
`GenStr` will be replaced by `String`. You can confirm this by running `javap` on their compiled
classes. The results are shown here:

```
class Gen extends java.lang.Object{
    java.lang.Object ob;
    Gen(java.lang.Object);
    java.lang.Object getob();
}
class GenStr extends java.lang.Object{
    java.lang.String str;
    GenStr(java.lang.String);
    java.lang.String getstr();
}
```

However, I see this-

```
public class GenStr<T extends java.lang.String> {
  T str;

  GenStr(T);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: aload_1
       6: putfield      #2                  // Field str:Ljava/lang/String;
       9: return

  T getstr();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: getfield      #2                  // Field str:Ljava/lang/String;
       4: areturn
}
```

---

```
class Gen<T> {
  T ob;

  Gen(T);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: aload_1
       6: putfield      #2                  // Field ob:Ljava/lang/Object;
       9: return

  T getob();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: getfield      #2                  // Field ob:Ljava/lang/Object;
       4: areturn
}
```

Why does the `.class` files still show the Formal Type parameter `<T>`?

Comment: Why wouldn't `.class` files show generic parameters? Generics are only erased at _runtime_.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does the .class files still show the Formal Type parameter ?

Simple: so that

- at compile time, the compiler can read such .class files and understand that the corresponding class is *generic*, and can be used in source code as generic
- at runtime, so that some code can inspect, well, "reflect" on the generic nature of that class

Type erasure refers to the fact that the information about the specific type used for an **instantiated** generic class isn't preserved. But the information *that this class* is generic needs to be in the class file. How else could the compiler know that `Gen` is generic in those situations where the compiler doesn't see Gen.java, but only Gen.class?!

Answer (score 1):

Type information about *the class* is still retained. Type information about *individual instances* is not.

So, you know that `Gen` has a class-level type parameter (notionally) called `T`.

You don't know the `T` for an instance of `Gen` at runtime. You can't even determine it from `getob`: that merely gives you a lower bound on the type (for example if `getob` returns a `String`, `T` could be `String`, `CharSequence`, `Serializable` or `Object`). And if it returns `null`, then `T` could be anything.

You can write code in Java against classes for which you have no source, only the compiled bytecode. The compiler needs information about the generics of such classes in order to be able to ensure they are used type correctly.